# Cron Job to Keep Daemon Running?

Tags: cron, python, daemon

let us suppose I have a cron job like this:

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/thedaemon
```

The daemon (it being a python daemon via `from daemon import runner`) will not allow multiple instances of itself, which in itself is quite nice. It one tries to initiate it while the daemon is already running, this is the result:

```
lockfile.LockTimeout: Timeout waiting to acquire lock for /tmp/thedaemon.pid
```

Of course the cron job doesn't care - it could keep dry-firing the command routinely so that in the case it is not running, it then starts running. But that is not very elegant.

More elegantly, is there a way to set up the cron job *to know if the daemon is running before initiating it?* **Perhaps a short-hand if-condition?**

**In short, how do I set up the cron job to ensure that the daemon is running?**

If running, do nothing. If not running, initiate.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want a system to automatically restart a crashed daemon? Does the daemon actually *have* to be run from a cron job? Can't it be run from an init script?

Comment: Why do you need to run the daemon from cron instead of init (sysv init/systemd/upstart/...)?

Comment: Cron in case something happens. Yes, a system upstart too. Basically - always run it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your python daemon in a shell script.
When you first initiate, check if the process is already running:

```
pid=$(cat pid.file)
ps -ef | grep $pid | grep <command to start daemon>
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "daemon already running" & exit 1
else
    <command to start daemon> & \
             echo $! > pid.file
fi
```